# Recursive query: comparing one field to another of the same class

Tags: django

I have a model similar to this one:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    departure = models.DateTimeField()
    arrival = models.DateTimeField()
```

And I want to make a query that returns objects where the arrival is at least 2 hours later than the departure.

```
Trip.objects.filter(arrival__gt = "departure" + timedelta(hours=2))
```

Is this even possible? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [filters that reference fields ont the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

> But what if you want to compare the value of a model field with
>   another field on the same model?

See this sample:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> Entry.objects.filter(mod_date__gt=F('pub_date') + timedelta(days=3))
```

For your case:

```
from django.db.models import F
Trip.objects.filter(arrival__gt = F('departure') + timedelta(hours=2))
```